# Как можно включить нумерацию строк в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Как можно включить нумерацию строк в Intellij IDEA? Intellij IDEA 2016.1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теоретически так:

`Settings` → `Editor` → `General` → `Appearance` → `Show line numbers`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вообще в IDE работает поиск и вы можете сами набрав `line numbers` попасть в нужное место настроек..

Answer (score 3):

Очень просто, жмете `ctrl+shift`, появится всплывающее меню, вводите то что вам нужно и затем `enter`

[image: всплывающее меню в intellij idea]